# prove characteristic function of an open set is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, characteristic-functions

The question is asking : prove $\chi_G$ is continuous at each point of $G$, where $G$ is an open set in $R$.
it may seem silly! but I ended up proving $\chi_G$ is NOT continuous.
$\chi^{-1}(0)=G^c$
$\chi^{-1}(1)=G$
G is open but singletons in R are closed, it is not like the preimage of "EVERY" open set is open then. so I assume we must conclude the characteristic function above is not continuous.
I know I am wrong of course. I need help with understanding where did I go wrong?

Comment: Look up the definition of "continuous at a point".  Then see if it works "for each point of $G$."

Answer (score 2):

The "pre-images of open sets are open" definition of continuity is only valid when you are saying the function is continuous as a whole, i.e. continuous everywhere in its domain. Your question is talking about a function being continuous *at a point*.

While there is a definition of "continuous at a point" that only uses open sets (see RobArthan's comment below), since your question refers to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, you can fall back on the good old $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

Comment: very clear! thank you indeed!

Comment: The generalisation of continuity at a point $x$ in the domain of a function $f: X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces is that for every open neighbourhood $A$ of $f(x)$ there is some neighbourhood $B$ of $x$ such that $f[B] \subseteq A$. This is equivalent to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition if $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, but it is a bit of an oversimplification to you **need** to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're almost right. The characteristic function of $A$, where $A$ is a subset of a topological space $X$, is continuous if and only if $A$ is *open and closed*.

Your argument essentially shows this. More precisely, $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are open in $\{0,1\}$, so $\chi_A^{-1}(\{1\})=A$ and $\chi_A^{-1}(\{0\})=X\setminus A$ must be open in order that $\chi_A$ is continuous. Therefore $A$ is open *and* closed.

The converse is easy.

However, if the problem is whether $\chi_G$ is continuous *at every point of $G$*, then it's completely obvious: every point of $G$ has a neighborhood where the function is constant.

Comment: Thank you very much! helped alot

Comment: You are talking about continuity on $X$ but the question is about continuity on $G$ (which you have renamed $A$).

Comment: @RobArthan OK, fixed