# Question about continuity of stopping time probability in proof of Dirichlet problem in Stein and Shakarchi

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems, potential-theory

In Chapter 6 in the book Functional analysis by Stein and Shakarchi the following theorem (Dirichlet problem) is proved:
[image: Dirichlet Problem]
$\mathcal{R}$ denotes a bounded open set and a point $y$ is called regular if
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_\ast^y=0) = 1$$
where $\tau^x = \inf\{t\geq 0: x+B_t\notin \mathcal{R}\}$ and $\tau_\ast^x = \inf\{t>0: x+B_t\notin \mathcal{R}\}$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion started at $0$ and $B_t^x = x+B_t$.

Now my question concerns a particular step in the proof of (b).[image: Proof of (b)]

I find the fact that $x\mapsto 1_{\{\omega':x+B_t(\omega')\in \mathcal{R}, \, \forall \epsilon\leq t \leq \delta\}}(\omega)$ should be continuous, hard to believe. Assume that $\mathcal{R} = \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$, the unit disk with the $0$ removed. Then if $B_{t_0}^y(\omega) = 0$ for precisely one $t_0\in [\epsilon,\delta]$ it is not necessarily so that $B_t^x(\omega) = 0$ for some $t\in [\epsilon,\delta]$ regardless of how close $x$ is to $y$. Could someone clarify this for me? Is this an error in the book?

Comment: Who said that indicator function is continuous?

Comment: I'm thinking about the line: '' ...the characteristic function of $\{B_t^x\in \mathcal{R},\text{all }\epsilon \leq t \leq \delta\}$ at $\omega$ converges to the characteristic function of $\{B_t^y\in \mathcal{R},\text{all }\epsilon \leq t \leq \delta\}$ at $\omega$, as $x\rightarrow y$...''

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: THIS ANSWER IS INCOMPLETE**

I think the key point is that $\mathcal{R}$ is an open set. Fix an $\omega$ such that $B_t$ is continuous. First note that $g(y,t)= B_t^y =y+B_t$ is jointly continuous.

Let us first show that $A:=\{y:y+B_t \in \mathcal{R}, \text{  all }\varepsilon\leq t \leq \delta\}$ is open. Suppsoe that $A$ is not open. Then there is a point $y \in A$ such that for every $n\geq 1$, you will get a $y_n \in (y-\frac{1}{n}, y+\frac{1}{n})$ such that $y_n \not\in A$. This means $y_n+B_{t_n} \not\in \mathcal{R}$ for some $t_n \in[\varepsilon,\delta]$. Now take a subsequence $y_{a_n}$ of $y_n$ such that for $y_{a_n}+B_{t_{a_n}}\not\in \mathcal{R}$, $t_{a_n} \in [\varepsilon,\delta]$, and $t_{a_n}\to t'$ for some $t'\in [\varepsilon,\delta]$ (you can always choose such a subsequence since $[\varepsilon,\delta]$ is compact). Now note that by construction $(y_{a_n},t_{a_n})\to(y,t')$ and therefore $y_{a_n}+B_{t_{a_n}} \to y+B_{t'} \in \mathcal{R}$ (using joint continuity of $B_t^y$). On the other hand $y_{a_n}+B_{t_{a_n}} \in \mathcal{R}^c$ which is closed, therefore the limit must be in $\mathcal{R}^c$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $A$ is open.

Coming to your problem, let $$f(y)=1\{B_t^y \in \mathcal{R}, \text{  all }\varepsilon\leq t \leq \delta\}= 1\{y \in A\}$$,
and we showed $A$ is open. Now you can conclude $f(y)$ is continuous on $A$ from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3581147/885456).

*It still does not show that $f$ is continuous everywhere.*

Comment: we only get continuity on $A$ though right? I think the problem occurs when $y\notin A$

Comment: You are right, it gives continuity on $A$, let me think and get back to you. For now, making an edit to point out that the solution is incomplete.

Comment: @OgvRubin Some more thoughts: it is clear what the book claimed can not be true for just any $y$. As for $1_A(.)$ to be continuous $A$ has to be both open and closed (which is not necessarily true here). It might be that the result is only claimed for $y\in \partial R$.

Comment: If $y\in \partial \mathcal{R}$ I don't think it is possible to conclude that $y\in A$ though